# How to make Pulseaudio work with MPD via network when using the client in Guest session?

Tags: pulseaudio, remote, guest-session, mpd

`mpc status` shows the playback is on, but "ERROR: Failed to open audio output". If I log in as [special purpose user](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession#Special_purpose_user), playback works fine. I have remote mpd server, but the audio should play in the client.

EDIT: I tried it again when I logged in Guest session right after boot. Then audio worked. Actually it seems that MPD pulseaudio output works only for the first proper user logged in after boot, and for Guest session only, if it is logged in first.

Comment: I may be missing something, but didn't you just say that you 'solved' it by using the "special purpose user" approach?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I updated the question. More clear now?

Comment: I think so. Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson 18.04 on server, 20.04 on client

Comment: Hmm.. Server should be irrelevant since guest session is a LightDM feature. And if you run LightDM on 20.04, the original security model for the guest session, provided by AppArmor, is broken. So it *should* work in the same way as when you log in directly to that "special purpose user".

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson well it does not as for Pulseaudio. I suspect some kind of permission issue.

Comment: I'm out of ideas, unfortunately. Hopefully somebody else can help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119075/discussion-between-jarno-and-gunnar-hjalmarsson).